# On the inequality $\sum_{i=1}^n|a_i-b_i|\le\big\lfloor \frac{n^2}{2}\big\rfloor$

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, inequality

Given $i,a_i,b_i\in\{1...n\},\space a_i\neq a_j,b_i\neq b_j,\forall i\neq j$ prove that
$$\sum_{i=1}^n|a_i-b_i|\le\big\lfloor \frac{n^2}{2}\big\rfloor$$
This problem was proposed by the new contributor  @user3458994 and it was closed by five users. I find it somewhat challenging (it does not have an immediate answer), but it is sufficiently well posed and, indeed, it can be solved by answering correctly.

There are many possible sums $\sum_{i=1}^n|a_i-b_i|$; in fact there are $n!$ possibilities (number of permutations of the set $\{1,2,\cdots,n\}$). The minimum for these sums is $0$ corresponding to the identity permutation $a_i\rightarrow b_i=a_i$ in which case the inequality is trivially verified. We expose one of these sums having a maximum value $M$ exactly equal to $\big\lfloor \frac{n^2}{2}\big\rfloor$. I believed no other sum has a value greater than $M$ in which case the problem would be false (am I wrong?).

Comment: For anybody who's interested, the referenced original question is [How to prove the following inequation?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3922224/602049). Note it currently has $2$ answers.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an almost immediate answer.

By expanding each term of $ |a_i - b_i|$ into the corresponding $\pm (a_i - b_i)$, we ge that
$$ \sum |a_i - b_i | = \sum c_i i,  $$ where $c_i \in \{-2, 0, 2 \}$ and $\sum c_i = 0 $.

Note: This is a necessary, but not sufficient condition. In particular, not all combinations of $c_i$ are possible from the absolute value, so we'd subsequently have to ensure that this can be satisfied. However, we're "lucky" enough that this works out for us.

When $n=2m$ is even, the maximum of $\sum c_i i $ is $ -2\times 1 -2 \times 2 \ldots - 2 \times m + 2 \times (m+1) + 2\times (m+2) + \ldots + 2 \times (2m) = 2m^2$.
This is satisfied with $a_i = i, b_i = n+1-i$, so it's the maximum of $ \sum |a_i - b_i|$.

When $n = 2m+1$ is odd, the maximum of $\sum c_i i $ is $ -2\times 1 -2\times 2 \ldots - 2\times m + 2\times (m+2) + 2\times (m+3) + \ldots + 2 \times (2m+1) = 2m(m+1)$.
This is satisfied with $a_i = i, b_i = n+1-i$, so it's the maximum of $ \sum |a_i - b_i|$.

Note: The necessary and sufficient condition is $ \sum_{i=1}^k c_{n+1-i} \geq 0$ for all $ 1 \leq k \leq n$. Once that is satisfied, there's a pretty natural way to assign the values. (Have a think about it.)

Comment: +1. This is a nice shortcut. I believe in the old question somebody else posted the same answer as yours but later it was deleted.

Comment: BTW it should be $b_i=n+1-i$. You had the same typo as I had in my original answer. You also have some typos in your $n=2m+1$ case (missing $m+1$ and $m+2$).

Comment: @NeatMath Thanks, fixed the typos of $ b_i = n+1 - i$ and $ m+3 \rightarrow m+2$. Note that when $n$ is odd, we do not have a $m+1$ term, in the sense that the coefficient is $0$. E.g. with $ i = m+1, a_i = m+1, b_i = m+1, |a_i - b_i | = (n+1) - (n+1) $.

Answer (score 1):

I have already given an answer in that post. I will post it again here. It's somewhat similar to the rearrangement inequality: When $\{a_i\}$ and $\{b_i=i\}$ have opposite order, the sum of the absolute difference reaches maximum (there could be other cases which also reach this maximum). The rest is just easy calculation.

---

**Lemma:** If $x>y,z>w$ then $|x-w|+|y-z|\geqslant |x-z|+|y-w|.$

WLOG we can assume $y\geqslant w$. Then $x>w$.

$$|x-w|+|y-z|\geqslant |x-z|+|y-w| \iff x-w+|y-z| \geqslant |x-z|+y-w \\
\iff |x-y|+|y-z|\geqslant |x-z|$$

which follows from the triangle inequality.

WLOG assume $b_i=i$. Then from the lemma the sum of absolute differences obtains its maximum value when $a_i$ is decreasing, i.e. $$\sum_{i=1}^n|a_i-i| \leqslant \sum_{i=1}^n |n+1-2i|.$$

If $n=2m$, $$\sum_{i=1}^n |n+1-2i|=2(2m-1) + 2(2m-3)+\cdots + 2(1)=2m^2 = \lfloor \frac{n^2}{2} \rfloor.$$

If $n=2m+1$, $$\sum_{i=1}^n |n+1-2i|=2(2m) + 2(2m-2)+\cdots + 2(0)=2m(m+1) = \lfloor \frac{n^2}{2} \rfloor.\blacksquare$$

Comment: Why WLOG $ y > w$? What about the $ y = w$ case? (You should just add it back in, it doesn't affect the next step.

Comment: @CalvinLin Thanks for pointing that out. I believe I was thinking $y, w$ are from $\{ b_j \}$ so they are different. But the lemma is true when they are the same. I'll update.

Comment: Oh I see what you are saying.

Comment: (+1) I'm not quite sure why you needed $ w = 0 $. You have $ |x - w | = x - w , |y-w| = y - w$, so the $w$ will cancel out.

Comment: I'm under the impression that $ x,y \in \{a_i \} $ and $ w, z \in \{b_i\}$, which is why we might have $ y = w$.

Comment: You are right. Thanks! Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

For any permutation, there's some $1 \le k \le n$ values of $i$ where

$$a_i - b_i \lt 0 \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

Thus, the remaining $n - k$ values of $i$ will be where

$$a_i - b_i \ge 0 \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

For simplicity, if need be, adjust the values of $a_i$ and $b_i$ so the $k$ values where \eqref{eq1A} hold are the ones where $1 \le i \le k$. This then gives

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\sum_{i = 1}^{n}|a_i - b_i| & = \sum_{i = 1}^{k}|a_i - b_i| + \sum_{i = k + 1}^{n}|a_i - b_i| \\
& = \sum_{i = 1}^{k}(b_i - a_i) + \sum_{i = k + 1}^{n}(a_i - b_i) \\
& = 2\sum_{i = 1}^{k}(b_i - a_i) - \sum_{i = 1}^{k}(b_i - a_i) + \sum_{i = k + 1}^{n}(a_i - b_i) \\
& = 2\sum_{i = 1}^{k}(b_i - a_i) + \sum_{i = 1}^{k}(a_i - b_i) + \sum_{i = k + 1}^{n}(a_i - b_i) \\
& = 2\sum_{i = 1}^{k}(b_i - a_i) + \sum_{i = 1}^{n}a_i - \sum_{i = 1}^{n}b_i \\
& = 2\sum_{i = 1}^{k}(b_i - a_i)
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

The last line comes from $\sum_{i = 1}^{n}a_i = \sum_{i = 1}^{n}b_i$ so the last $2$ terms of the line before cancel. In \eqref{eq3A}, the maximum value comes from the $b_i$ being the largest allowed $k$ values, i.e., $n - k + 1 \le b_i \le n$, and $a_i$ being the smallest allowed $k$ values, i.e., $1 \le a_i \le k$. Thus,

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
2\sum_{i = 1}^{k}(b_i - a_i) & \le 2\left(\sum_{i = n - k + 1}^{n}i - \sum_{i = 1}^{k}i \right) \\
& = 2\left(\frac{k((n - k + 1) + n)}{2} - \frac{k(k + 1)}{2}\right) \\
& = k(n - k + 1 + n - k - 1) \\
& = 2k(n - k)
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{4}\label{eq4A}$$

Note $f(k) = 2k(n - k)$ is a concave down parabola with a maximum at $k = \frac{n}{2}$. For even $n$, this value of $k$ is an integer, with it giving a maximum value of \eqref{eq4A} as

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
2k(n - k) & \le 2\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)\left(n - \frac{n}{2}\right) \\
& = n\left(\frac{n}{2}\right) \\
& = \left\lfloor \frac{n^2}{2} \right\rfloor
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{5}\label{eq5A}$$

For odd $n$, the same maximum value is achieved with $k = \frac{n - 1}{2}$ and $k = \frac{n + 1}{2}$. Using the first value, we get from \eqref{eq4A} that

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
2k(n - k) & \le 2\left(\frac{n - 1}{2}\right)\left(n - \frac{n - 1}{2}\right) \\
& = (n - 1)\left(\frac{n + 1}{2}\right) \\
& = \frac{n^2 - 1}{2} \\
& = \left\lfloor \frac{n^2}{2} \right\rfloor
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{6}\label{eq6A}$$

This shows the stated inequality always holds. Note [Piquito](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/219998/piquito)'s [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3924380/602049) gives an explicit example where the maximum possible value is reached for even $n$.